# Where to download and install wireless drive for BCM 4365?

Tags: wireless, drivers

Hello can any one help me download and install the necessary network drivers required for my network card BCM 4365. Please provide all the details of the steps involved!

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
x86_64

And FYI this one's not a duplicate and I want every detail information for downloading and installing the wireless driver!

Comment: The exact process depends on your Ubuntu version and achitecture. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: lsb_release -d and also: arch. Edit your question to add the results.

Comment: @chilli555 Please help me through this!

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection. Open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and enter these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerkl6uqal5ylv3/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wireless*.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should now be working.

If you have no internet access, you will need to download these .deb packages on another computer and transfer them on a USB key or similar from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Please select 'Precise' which is the codename for Ubuntu 12.04. Since yours is a 64-bit system, select, if there is a difference, the amd64 package.

build-essential and its dependencies;
dpkg-dev,
g++,
gcc,
libc6-dev and
make

linux-headers-generic and its dependency;
linux-headers matching your running kernel version. Find out with:

```
uname -r
```

If, for example, your running kernel version is reported as 3.2.0-54-generic, then you need linux-headers-3.2.0-54-generic.

dkms and its dependencies not already installed above;
coreutils
module-init-tools
patch

You also need the driver package itself: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerkl6uqal5ylv3/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb

Once you have all these packages on the USB key, drag and drop them to the desktop of the Ubuntu machine. Install them all at once from the terminal:

```
cd Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If a package is missing, download it, add it to the desktop and install again.

Comment: Is there any other way cause i don't even have temporary wired ethernet connection!! any other methods like downloading using windows and installing it offline in ubuntu!

Comment: Downloading all the packages and all their dependencies and dependencies of the dependencies (!!) is a tedious and difficult process but it can be done. Are you unable to beg or borrow an ethernet connection or else a USB wireless for just a few moment?

Comment: Yeah, you got it right! That's why I am seeking for help which doesn't involve internet connection in ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my wifi drivers before. You may try this method of downloading from synaptiks, the necessary files involved. [Here's the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352616/whys-my-wifi-hotspot-connection-failing-to-get-established/352711#352711).
Also, if you don't have an active internet connection, try ubuntu live cd and check if the drivers are working; it probably will. In that case, you can download them in to a pen-drive and procedd to install them to HDD.