# Why's my wifi-Hotspot connection failing to get established?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

What I did:

1. Open system settings, Network, **Wireless**.
2. Clicked "**Create Hotspot**"
3. (Nothing happened). Clicked **network icon** in panel
4. Create New wireless network
5. Entered name and password
6. Entered **SSID** "ubuntu"
7. set **IPV6** setting to Ignored (default)
8. Tried Create-Hotspot again and failed!
9. Error message : "**WIFI Disconnected**"

I'll update any necessary info here as you request.

Comment: i tried the steps mentioned by shivshnkr...
but i find the following situation ****"
**spartacus@spartacus:~$ sudo ap-hotspot configure
Detecting configuration...
Detected tun0 as the network interface connected to the Internet. Press ENTER if this is correct or enter the desired interface below (e.g.- eth0, ppp0 etc.): Detected wlan0 as your WiFi interface. Press ENTER if this is correct or enter the desired interface (e.g.- wlan1):
Enter the desired Access Point name or press ENTER to use the default one (myhotspot):
Enter the desired WPA Passphrase below or press ENTER to use the default on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This have bugged me for quite some time, especially after any fresh installs or updates. I found a solution which worked perfectly for me. For those of you who have the same trouble with their laptop wifi [**Toshiba** or **HP** laptop-wifi-drivers in particular] this will surely help you.

1. Deactivate currently active Broadcom drivers from additional-drivers. Blacklist **BCMA** and **BRCM80211** by typing in terminal:

   ```
   echo "blacklist bcma" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   echo "blacklist brcm80211" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
2. Reboot now and download Synaptic Package Manager (makes it easier to find our files).
3. Search "**bcm43**" and download these 4 (they might prompt for some other dependency files - just accept them too)

   - bcmwl-kernel-source
   - broadcom-sta-common
   - broadcom-sta-source
   - firmware-b43-installer
4. Reboot
5. Now, you may check if your wifi is working (testing your hotspot or connecting to a network etc.)
6. If it isn't, then go to additional-drivers and activate the newly downloaded drivers followed by a reboot.

Note: **additional drivers** are found in System-settings > Software sources > additional drivers

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a hotspot, you could try installing ap-hotspot. It works fine for connecting to almost all wifi devices, android phones, etc.

To install it:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

Next, to start the hotspot:

```
$ sudo ap-hotspot start
```

It asks you which adapter's internet you want to share, name of the network, password, etc. in an interactive manner.

To stop the hotspot :

```
$ sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

To configure it:

```
$ sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

If any problem, hope this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) helps.